# How to treat old entries? Separate table, partition or just index?

Tags: mysql, sql

for simplification, we operate an ad network and have 2 tables:

- campaigns (columns: id, status)
  status can be active or inactive, 100k new entries weekly, 95 % of entries change to status "inactive" within 72 hours
- clicks (columns: id, campaign_id, created_time)
  list of clicks related to campaigns. 1 mio new entries weekly

99 % of queries are related to "active" campaigns and last 30 days clicks. Inactive campaigns and clicks older than 30 days are only used in some statistics queries. After 2 years there are 10 mio entries in campaigns table and 100 mio entries in clicks table, though only a fraction is being used on most queries, I suspect this is very inefficient.

Solutions:

1. Create a table "inactive_campaigns" and "inactive_clicks" and move "old" data there regularly
2. Create a partition on each table to move the "old data" there
3. Just stick with the indexes on campaigns.status and clicks.created_time

Did I forget any better solution?
Which of these solutions are the best coding practice and why?
Is there a speed different between 1) and 2)?

Thank you!

Comment: Just an oppinion. Option 1 seems to be the best solution for you.  Moving historical data to separate tables is a straightforward method. As long the users can live with having to query other tables for old data. And you can partition the tables with old data

Answer (score 1):

As 99% of the queries are on last 30 days clicks, it is better to optimize the table such that query is fastest on these records.

**1)Create a table "inactive_campaigns" and "inactive_clicks" and move "old" data there regularly.**

*I would use this option if there is never or rarely needed historical data to be shown up in any reports. This is a good choice, but practially "moving" old data would require you to write code that does the moving to other tables.*

**2)Create a partition on each table to move the "old data" there**

*This is a good approach to keep all of the data together, Partitioning is good way which will lighten the IO hits when queried. It is important that the query which runs on this partitioned table does partition pruning/elimination. Eg: if you partitioned on a date column, you would check the input to the query is also in the correct format that enables the optimizer to search the relevant partition only.*

```
select * 
   from my_large_partitioned_table 
  where date_of_campaign =dateadd(-30,day,CURRENT_DATE)
```

This  would use partition pruning/partition eliminiation

If the query/framework does something like this

```
select * 
   from my_large_partitioned_table 
  where dateadd(-30,day,date_of_campaign) <= CURRENT_DATE
```

most likely partition pruning wouldn't take place(depends on database), as function (dateadd) on partitioned column would confuse the optimizer and would result in a full scan of the partitioned table.

**3) Just stick with the indexes on campaigns.status and clicks.created_time**

*This choice would be my last preferred approach. If your database licensing doesnt allow partitioning this is a choice you have to make.*

Alternatively for the approaches you have mentioned, i suggest you compress the data which is seldom changing, especially the archival data. It would save space and also makes the query faster, (compressed data needs less scans). Also having indexes on status and created_time can improve the query performance which you gain from partitioing